# How to crop a bitmap from bottom part and show it imageview

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

From image URL am downloading image using picasso lib, How can i cutoff(crop) bottom part of image and show it in Imageview.

I used below code which makes crop at center, but now i need cutoff at bottom which is more than 150 height.

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(offerImage.getUrl()).resize(500, 150).centerCrop().onlyScaleDown().into(holder.ivOfferImage);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for but you probably need to look for another method instead of `.centerCrop()` because it will only crop from the center as its name suggests.

Comment: I need crop image into 500x150 and cutoff more than 150dp from bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys Use Transform form Picasso lib where you crop images based on gravity.

Use below code to cutoff at bottom

```
 Picasso.with(mContext).load(offerImage.getUrl()).transform(new CropTransformation(500,150), CropTransformation.GravityHorizontal.CENTER,CropTransformation.GravityVertical.TOP)).into(holder.ivOfferImage);
```

For more details check here - https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations/blob/master/transformations/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/picasso/transformations/CropTransformation.java

Thanks.